# HTML FORMS - Passing values to two different forms on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am having problems trying to pass values to two different forms on the same page. The page is populated with 16 radio buttons (which I’ve turned into boxes for display reasons) and they all hold a value (e.g. 001). Both of the forms jobs are to somehow grab the active/selected radio button value and post it to a PHP file so database changes can be made. Instead of a submit button, I am using an anchor to pass a JavaScript submit function. I have tried having 
both forms cover the whole page but still didn't have any luck.

I’ll post some code below to help you understand.

PS. If you need more code to understand, I can post it to pastebin.

```
<li>
<form id="form_ready" method="post" action="../backend/screen.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="screenid" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pickupid" value="document.activeElement.value;" />
    <a onclick="document.getElementById('form_ready').submit();">READY</a>
</form>
</li>
<li>
<form id="form_c" method="post" action="../backend/screen.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="pickupid" value="document.activeElement.value;" />
    <a onclick="document.getElementById('form_c').submit();">COLLECTED</a>
</form>
</li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
<div id="container">
<div id="table">
    <div id="tr1">
    <div id="td1">
        <input type="radio" name="pickup" id="1" value="001" />
        <label for="1"> <span>001</span> </label>
    </div>
    <div id="td2">
        <input type="radio" name="pickup" id="2" value="002" />
        <label for="2"> <span>002</span> </label>
    </div>
    <div id="td3">
        <input type="radio" name="pickup" id="3" value="003" />
        <label for="3"> <span>003</span> </label>
    </div>
    <div id="td4">
        <input type="radio" name="pickup" id="4" value="004" />
        <label for="4"> <span>004</span> </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: So is the only difference between the two forms the value of the hidden "status" field? You could have one form with all the controls in it, then use JS to set the value of the hidden "status" just before submitting. Or if you used actual submit buttons instead of anchors you could use them to set the "status" instead of a hidden field, and then you wouldn't need any Javascript.

Comment: I need two forms because one is to show that the item is ready to be collected and the other is to remove it from the pickup screen. I thought of changing the achors to a submit button, but I still need to be able to grab the value from the selected radio button. If you have any ideas on how to do that, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the suggestion in the comments and use only one form, here's how to grab the value from the selected radio button:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var valueSelected;
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].checked) valueSelected = inputs[i].value;
}
```

`valueSelected` will contain the value of the selected radio.

If you ever need to reduce the type to "radio" only for some reason, you can check an input type with `inputs[i]['type'] === 'radio'` in the for loop.

---

The best would probably still be to set a class for your "radio" inputs, it will allow the loop to be more specific, hence a more efficient code, for example:

```
<input type="radio" class="myRadio">
```

and in JS: `var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('myRadio');`